# AZDO - Variable it's not assigned correctly?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have the following strange problem with azure devops:

Let's assume that i have a branch called `branch-playground` and I have this pipeline.

First case with `contains`:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Stage_2
  displayName: 'test'
  variables:
  - name: customBranchName
    ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/') }}:
      value: $[ replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') ]
    ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/') }}:
      value: $[ replace(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') ]
  jobs:
  - job: Test
    steps:
      - ${{ if contains('branch-playground', variables.customBranchName.value ) }}:
        - bash: echo "print"
```

In this case will be ok, the bash script will be executed.

BUT the strange thing is when i try to use `eq`.

```yaml
... same as before...
  jobs:
  - job: Test
    steps:
      - ${{ if eq('branch-playground', variables.customBranchName.value ) }}:
        - bash: echo "print"
```

Now, this bash script it's not executed...

The log from Job execution:

```yaml
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: ubuntu-latest
Agent: Azure Pipelines 2
Started: Today at 21:57
Duration: 5s

Job preparation parameters
Variables:
  customBranchName:
    Parsing expression: <replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')>
    Evaluating: replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')
    Expanded: replace('refs/heads/branch-playground', 'refs/heads/', '')
    Result: 'branch-playground'
```

Can anyone have any idea why it's happening this?

Answer (score 0):

The variable is `variables.customBranchName`, not `variables.customBranchName.value`.

Comment: Thx, but i tried i think all the combinations and it's not working.

I also tried with ```variables['customBranchName']```...

Answer (score 0):

> AZDO - Variable it's not assigned correctly?

You could try to use following syntax:

```
- bash: echo "print"
  condition: eq(variables.customBranchName, 'branch-playground')
```

Please check the detailed sample from the document:

[Use a template parameter as part of a condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-template-parameter-as-part-of-a-condition)

```
steps:
- script: echo I did a thing
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.doThing }}', 'true'))
```